# Is it possible to add response http headers in web.config?

Tags: asp.net

In my application I need to set a http response header. I'd like to do this in web.config.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution**
Finally, after a long search I found the solution. Create a class with this code:

```
public class myHTTPHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{

    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(context_EndRequest);
    }

    void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.AddHeader("Content-Language", "*");

    }

    #endregion
}
```

(Don't ask me why to use this event, but it works..)

Now add a line in web.config in the HttpModule section:

```
    <httpModules>
        <add type="namespace.myHTTPHeaderModule, assembly name" name="headers" />
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
```

And that's it!

Comment: Please see my blog post on this subject here: http://sudhanshutheone.net/2013/10/14/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https/. although the issue I was trying to solve was different but i needed to add/remove HTTP headers. The event to do this in is HttpContext.PreSendRequestHeaders. You can also do this from IIS settings or IIS's config as shown here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

Answer (score 72):

The best way to do this would be the `<customHeaders>` element of the `web.config` file. Note that this only works for IIS version 7 and above.

The configuration to add your example header would be:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Language" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more information see the [IIS "Custom Headers" Configuration Reference page](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders)

Comment: The problem with this is, it only works for IIS >= 7, if you have IIS6, you're out of luck.

Comment: The IIS ref link now redirects to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders/

Answer (score 1):

You can always add an item to the configuration.appSettings section.

Then your master page, custom base page class, or a specific page can set those http headers by reading from the web.config

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that you can do it on the web.config

So far I know the best options you have are:

- Create an HTTPModule where you set the header for all responses
- Add the header on the IIS

Here you have the reference on MSDN:

[Custom HttpModule Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858%28VS.71%29.aspx)

This link has an implementation of an HTTPModule that seems to be what you need

<strike>http://idunno.org/archive/2006/08/01/252.aspx</strike>

Comment: How do I create a HTTPModule to set the header?

Answer (score 1):

I believe none of the answers here are comprehensive, so here's mine:

Please see my blog post on how to add a custom HTTP module to add/remove HTTP headers [here](http://sudhanshutheone.net/2013/10/14/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https/). Although the issue I was trying to solve was different but I too needed to add/remove HTTP headers. A gist of the blog post is as follows:

The event to do this in is HttpContext.PreSendRequestHeaders. You can also do this from IIS settings or IIS's config as shown on [IIS Knowledge base](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders). This config file (applicationHost.config) is located at ***%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config*** for a default installation.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in functionality that does this

You can make an `HttpModule` that reads headers from web.config and adds them to the response.

Comment: You should add some coding example