# Browser cache not expiring

Tags: asp.net, browser-cache, cache-control

I am developing my application in asp.net and wanted force refreshing of .js files after certain period of time. In order to test that in local environment, I made following change to my web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="must-revalidate max-age=120" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

As I understand cache-control, based on above settings, browser cache should expire after 2:00 minutes and any new postback should send a request to webserver to check if newer version of .js is avialable or not. I used fiddler to monitor network traffic and I don't see any request for js file. The browser I am using is Chrome. So I used dev tools to monitor network traffic. I see that the browser is using cached version of that file.

Are there any other settings that would force the browser to expire the cached files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Cache-Control` is invalid, try separate values by comma: `must-revalidate, max-age=120`.

Relevant excerpt from [RFC 7234 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2):

> Cache-Control   = 1#cache-directive

> cache-directive = token [ "=" ( token / quoted-string ) ]

And ABNF List Extension from [RFC 7230 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-7):

> A construct "#" is defined, similar to "*", for defining
> comma-delimited lists of elements.  The full form is "<n>#<m>element"
> indicating at least <n> and at most <m> elements, each separated by a
> single comma (",") and optional whitespace (OWS).

Also make sure to put new configuration in right place. For more information check [Is it possible to add response http headers in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922178/is-it-possible-to-add-response-http-headers-in-web-config).