# What code should be used to set server http headers for character encoding in IIS 10?

Tags: iis

When running a website analysis I receive two messages:

**The first message is:** "The charset encoding (UTF-8) is set correctly".

I'm assuming this is a result of my webpage's meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

So far so good.

**The second message is:** "The character encoding is not specified in the HTTP header.".

After a lot of investigation, it seems that I need to add similar instructions to my server, which is IIS 10 on a shared hosting platform.

I have tried to do so in two ways:

1. I added to my web.config file:

```
    <system.web>
        <globalization 
           requestEncoding="utf-8"
           responseEncoding="utf-8"
        />
    </system.web>
```

Still getting the same error message.

2. I changed the above in my web.config file to read:

```
    <system.web>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"></globalization>
    </system.web>
```

Still getting the same error message.

I then went into my Plesk control panel and located IIS Settings> Additional headers> Enter custom value. Again, after extensive research, I have been unable to locate the correct entries that would create the proper character encoding for the server's HTTP header.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

That link you suggested appears to provide an answer for the correct syntax to use for adding a custom header in web.config, but I still get the same error message. So, if in fact that link shows the correct syntax for adding the headers, then the question still remains as to the correct syntax for the header information. Here is my last attempt that failed to correct the error:

```
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="requestEncoding" value="utf-8" />
            <add name="responseEncoding" value="utf-8" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add response http headers in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922178/is-it-possible-to-add-response-http-headers-in-web-config)

Comment: Error still exists after I changed syntax for web.config file as shown in your suggested link.

Comment: Your change is invalid. You might guess what kind of change gives you HTTP headers like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#syntax

Comment: 1. Learn how to use tools like developer tools in a browser to analyze HTTP headers. 2. Do experiments with web.config settings, and see what changes lead to what behaviors.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried lots of different approaches over many hours of testing and extensive research. I did all of that before posting this question to see if anyone had any actual knowledge of the correct syntax for creating custom character encoding for HTTP headers on IIS 10.

Comment: You can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `<system.web>` is used in IIS versions < 7.  
The following solution works in **IIS 10**

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add safe charset to Content-Type response header" enabled="true">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Type" pattern="^(text|application)\/[\w-]+$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; charset=UTF-8" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

**Explanation**:

For every server response, we check whether the mimetype is textual (html, css, js, json, etc.). If that's the case we **append** the charset to the `Content-Type` header value. This avoids issues where Unicode charset is set for images or movies for example which have a binary encoding.

**Why the solution below does not work**

```
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="requestEncoding" value="utf-8" />
            <add name="responseEncoding" value="utf-8" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
```

Inside the `customHeaders` tag, you try to add HTTP headers `requestEncoding` and `responseEncoding` which the browser doesn't know about. What you should do instead:

```
<add name="Content-Type" value="charset=utf-8" />
```

However, the problem with this solution is that whatever the value of the original `Content-Type` header was gets overwritten. Also, this header is replaced in every response indiscriminately. This might cause problems with images for example.